# SilverStripe: How to set/ specify the icon for GridField custom action button

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am trying to create a GridField custom button. I followed the official documentation. Following is the class form the SilverStripe official page.

```
class GridFieldCustomAction implements GridField_ColumnProvider, GridField_ActionProvider, GridField_ActionMenuItem
{

    public function getTitle($gridField, $record, $columnName)
    {
        return 'Custom action';
    }

    public function getCustomAction($gridField, $record)
    {
        if (!$record->canEdit()) {
            return;
        }

        return GridField_FormAction::create(
            $gridField,
            'CustomAction'.$record->ID,
            'Custom action',
            "docustomaction",
            ['RecordID' => $record->ID]
         )->addExtraClass(
            'action-menu--handled'
        );
    }

    public function getExtraData($gridField, $record, $columnName)
    {
        $field = $this->getCustomAction($gridField, $record);

        if (!$field) {
            return;
        }

        return $field->getAttributes();
    }

    public function getGroup($gridField, $record, $columnName)
    {
        return GridField_ActionMenuItem::DEFAULT_GROUP;
    }

    public function augmentColumns($gridField, &$columns) 
    {
        if (!in_array('Actions', $columns)) {
            $columns[] = 'Actions';
        }
    }

    public function getColumnAttributes($gridField, $record, $columnName) 
    {
        return ['class' => 'grid-field__col-compact'];
    }

    public function getColumnMetadata($gridField, $columnName) 
    {
        if ($columnName === 'Actions') {
            return ['title' => ''];
        }
    }

    public function getColumnsHandled($gridField) 
    {
        return ['Actions'];
    }

    public function getColumnContent($gridField, $record, $columnName) 
    {
        $field = $this->getCustomAction($gridField, $record);

        if (!$field) {
            return;
        }

        return $field->Field();
    }

    public function getActions($gridField) 
    {
        return ['docustomaction'];
    }

    public function handleAction(GridField $gridField, $actionName, $arguments, $data) 
    {
        if ($actionName !== 'docustomaction') {
            return;
        }
        // perform your action here

        // output a success message to the user
        Controller::curr()->getResponse()->setStatusCode(
            200,
            'Do Custom Action Done.'
        );
    }
}
```

I am struggling to add the custom icon for the button or specify the style class of the button. I can change the column class name. But I cannot find a way for the button. How can I do that?

Comment: Where in your example code are you trying to set the icon?

Comment: Hi, I tried putting HTML code in getTitle method.  It did not work. I still cannot find a place to do that too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this using `->setAttribute('classNames', 'font-icon-<your-icon>');`

i.e. for "edit" icon the code would looks like this:

```
return GridField_FormAction::create(
    $gridField,
    'CustomAction'.$record->ID,
    'Custom action',
    "docustomaction",
    [
        'RecordID' => $record->ID
    ]
)
    ->addExtraClass('action-menu--handled')
    ->setAttribute('classNames', 'font-icon-edit');
```

You can find all available icons on this page:
https://gbaumeister.github.io/ss4-icons/